# Help to identify this bicycle, please

Tags: identify-this-bike

Need to identify this cool bike in hopes to restore it.

Serial # M3 G2058
Decals read: GT 4130 CRO MO, and TEAM on one 
It appears to have been Chrome with decals and since painted over?[image]

Thanks to all who try to help us.

BTW - Cool site!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one piece seat-stay/chain-stay construction looks like a Hutch<sup>*</sup> from the early 80's however, having both the left & right side stays made from one bent tube doesn't match up exactly with anything I have looked at while browsing the [BMX Museum](http://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/hutch/). It might be something from the late 70s (they only have from 1980 on pictured there). Or it might be a <strike>knock-off</strike> cheap copy of the Hutch design. That might be a good place to continue your search.

Based on the eBay prices of some of these bikes, I'd say you've *likely* got yourself a valuable project on your hands!

<sup>*I picked Hutch based on one that was similar looking on eBay that came up in a search for "bicycle gt 4130 cro mo team".</sup>

Comment: Got this data today ... M = Merida (Taiwan)
3 = Nineteen 83
G = July
2058 = frame production # - Similar to a "Mongoose" frame

Comment: Glad you found it! Were the BMX Museum people able to help you decode the "VIN"?